# The given code using useselector is not fetching data

Tags: reactjs

Here in functional component useSelector is not working and not fetching any images.I have also attached my codesandbox link below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-use-redux-in-your-react-app-with-axios-forked-sgzunt?file=/src/component/users.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getUsers } from "../store/actions/usersAction";

function Users(props) {
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users);
  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  if (!users.length) return null;

  const userData = users.map((user) => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment key={user.id}>
        <h6> {user.first_name} </h6>
        <p> {user.last_name} </p>
        <p> {user.email}</p>
        <p>
          <img key={user.avatar} src={user.avatar} alt="avatar" />
        </p>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  });

  return <div>{userData}</div>;
}

export default Users;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a bit confused with your code. You are using a function that returns a function that takes dispatch as an argument, likely as part of a redux-thunk action creator (i.e. async actions). https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic

You are updating your state with the `users` for `userReducer` object so your selector function should be `state.users.users`

I just updated with classic Js and it is working. I am trying to achieve your functionality by using nested arrow functions.

This is the working code in Classic Js.

[image: Edit How to use redux in your react app with Axios (forked)]

Comment: updated [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-use-redux-in-your-react-app-with-axios-forked-nvih3e)

Answer (score 0):

users is empty when your components mount thats why its not rendering anything, the action is called in next line.

```
const [data,setData] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{ setData(users) },[users])
```

replace below code

```
if (!data.length) return null;
```

replace map function too.

```
const userData = data.map((user) => {
return (
  <React.Fragment key={user.id}>
    <h6> {user.first_name} </h6>
    <p> {user.last_name} </p>
    <p> {user.email}</p>
    <p>
      <img key={user.avatar} src={user.avatar} alt="avatar" />
    </p>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
});
```

Comment: Please update the code in codesandbox link